# Reading a connection string from a class library

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, app-config, class-library

I am currently struggling to read a connection string from the `App.config` inside my WinForms application from my Class Library (and Unit Testing).

I added a 'test' entry to the `App.config`;

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyConnString" connectionString="Test;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My TestMethod looks like this;

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestConnection1()
    {
        string connString = "";

        if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"] != null)
        {
            connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        string expected = "Test;";
        string actual = connString;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

This, obviously, fails. `Actual`'s value is empty.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: does expected == actual returns true?

Comment: See the picture I added to the bottom of the question.
Actual equals "", expected equals "Test;".

Comment: Will something like this work `string connString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;`

Comment: @DJ KRAZE,
If I put `0` as index, it returns me a connectionstring for SQLExpress "aspnetdb.mdf".
If I put `1` as index, I get an exception (`IndexOutOfRangeException`), so obviously my string is not found.

Comment: what I have works on my end but mind you, that I have a valid config file setting in my app.

Comment: My `App.config` is default, except by adding the connectionStrings-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add connection string key into Test project's config as well.

Comment: So you want me to add a Connection String key to my Unit Testing project?
I heard it's not best practice to have an App.config in a class library or Unit Testing project.

Comment: yes you should, nothing wrong in adding it to unit testing project and it is required to have config as you are testing that specific scenario, and ya if you add config to class library it is of no use.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I didn't know I had to copy over the `App.config` to the Unit Testing for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment to DJ Kraze: "*@DJ KRAZE, If I put 0 as index, it returns me a connectionstring for SQLExpress "aspnetdb.mdf". If I put 1 as index, I get an exception (`IndexOutOfRangeException`), so obviously my string is not found."*

The problem is you forgot the configuration element.  For example:

Referenced from MSDN: [Storing and Retrieving Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add name="Name" 
       providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" 
       connectionString="Valid Connection String;" />
    </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

The machine.config file also contains a `<connectionStrings>` section, which contains connection strings used by Visual Studio. When retrieving connection strings by provider name from the **app.config** file in a Windows application, the connection strings in machine.config get loaded first, and then the entries from **app.config**. Adding clear immediately after the connectionStrings element removes all inherited references from the data structure in memory, so that only the connection strings defined in the local **app.config** file are considered.